# Move ribbon in circle with push/shift and unshift/pop

Tags: html, angularjs

I've got following code:

```js
angular.module("myApp", []).controller("myController", function ($scope) {
  $scope.myList = [
    { text: "1" },
    { text: "2" },
    { text: "3" },
    { text: "4" },
    { text: "5" },
  ];
});
```

```css
.ribbon {
  display: flex;
}
.arrow {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: grey;
  color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.items {
  display: flex;
  overflow: hidden;
  //width: 150px;
  border-color: 1px solid grey;
}
.item {
  border: 1px solid blue;
  width: 50px;
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div class="ribbon" ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myController">
  <div class="arrow arrowLeft" ng-click="myList.push(myList.shift())">&larr;</div>
  <div class="items">
    <div class="item" ng-repeat="item in myList">{{ item.text }}</div>
  </div>
  <div class="arrow arrowRight" ng-click="myList.unshift(myList.pop())">&rarr;</div>
</div>
```

I've got there a simple list with some items. This items are in a element with should be something like a ribbon. I've also got two arrow-buttons (left and right). When I click on right, the whole ribbon moves to right (in a circle) and so when item 5 is the last, it pops op as first and the first moves to second etc. My goal is it to move the ribbon around in a circle but it should be the other way around. When I click on the right arrow, it should move to left (so the first item is now last etc). When I click on left, it should move to right (last is now first etc). How can I do this? I tried to just switch the `ng-click` but it seems to to work. Any ideas?

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I FOUND THE SOLUTION**

Switching the to ng-click works, I just saw it wrong - sorry!

But still thanks and cheers.

**HERE YOU GO:**

```js
angular.module("myApp", []).controller("myController", function ($scope) {
  $scope.myList = [
    { text: "1" },
    { text: "2" },
    { text: "3" },
    { text: "4" },
    { text: "5" },
  ];
});
```

```css
.ribbon {
  display: flex;
}
.arrow {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: grey;
  color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.items {
  display: flex;
  overflow: hidden;
  //width: 150px;
  border-color: 1px solid grey;
}
.item {
  border: 1px solid blue;
  width: 50px;
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div class="ribbon" ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myController">
  <div class="arrow arrowLeft" ng-click="myList.push(myList.shift())">&larr;</div>
  <div class="items">
    <div class="item" ng-repeat="item in myList">{{ item.text }}</div>
  </div>
  <div class="arrow arrowRight" ng-click="myList.unshift(myList.pop())">&rarr;</div>
</div>
```